# exp:channel:categories not displaying all categories in a group

Tags: categories

So I have a channel (dog) with multiple category groups assigned to it. I'm trying to build a navigation and have the following code for the DOG dropdown list:

`{exp:channel:categories channel="dog" style="linear" show_empty="yes" category_group="6"}
{category_name}
{/exp:channel:categories}`

Out of 10 categories (all have entries), only 5 show up.

I'm using the following code to show categories under BUNNY and all categories show up.

`{exp:channel:categories channel="bunny" style="linear" show_empty="yes" category_group="1"}
{category_name}
{/exp:channel:categories}`

The only difference that I have noted between the two channels is that DOG has multiple category groups assigned (6|7|8) while BUNNY only has one (1).

I have taken the code out of the full template, and placed it into a separate template with no other code to make sure nothing else was interfering and the results are the same.

Thanks for any help/tips/suggestions you can provide.

EE v2.7.2

Comment: Also wanted to mention that there are no children categories in category group 6. It's just a regular run-of-the-mill category group.

Comment: So just to clarify: category group 6 has 10 categories? Not that 6|7|8 would yield the 10?

Comment: Correct - category group has 10. There is also category group 7 and 8 assigned to the same channel, but I only want to show the 10 from category group 6.

Comment: You could try removing the channel parameter as I don't think it's required if you give it a category group ID. I don't know why that would make a difference but it's possible the channel is restricting the list somehow.

Comment: Yeah I went down that road too with the same exact results. I think I've tried every possible combination.

Answer (score 1):

There are other parameters that effect whether a category has entries and therefore should be shown.

1. show_expired
2. show_future_entries
3. status

[From the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/categories.html#status)

Could one of those be the problem?

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I should have mentioned that I tried all of those - alone, together, only a few, all of them at the same time. I still only show 5 categories under Dog.

Answer (score 1):

Try Gwcode categories and check if you get the results you are expecting.

Comment: Also check if you have included all the statuses of the entries and try parent_only="no" parameter.